# how can I get an array of all objects in w2ui

Tags: w2ui

I am trying to subsequently manipulate the menus and tabs of a w2ui application.
In order to implement a generic solution, I added an additional attribute (zndesktop) to the related elements. Now I am looking for a generic method which gives me an array of all objects having this attribute.

Of course, I can hardcode such a query. But I am asking if there is an generic approach (for example `w2ui.objects`) which would return an array of all UI objects created for the application (recursive search)

Answer (score 0):

w2ui objects are actually stored directly in the global w2ui object using their `name`, until you destroy them.

Example: if you create a grid with

```
$('#grid').w2grid({ 
    name: 'my_grid', 
    ...
});
```

Then you can access it with `w2ui.my_grid` or `w2ui['my_grid']`.

Of course you can also iterate the `w2ui` object (or rather its properties) just like any other JS object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As there are nested objects, such an iteration needs to go in depth. I wonder if there is a way other than hardcode this depth iteration. Iterate w2ui might not work as there are other properties which are not user defined.